# I cant find my link on the home page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am having trouble with finding my  link. When I open up my html and css in the file, I cannot visibly see it (I believe it is stuck under my div, even though the z-index is higher?) I am not entirely sure why, any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Derpycats.com</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!--Background (Carbon Fibre)-->
    <body background="background.jpg" alt="Background" />

    <!--Header-->
    <h1 id="header">DerpyCats.com</h1>
    <div id="headerdiv"></div>

    <!---Links-->
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com">Home</a>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Sets the pixel density to "fill browser" */
* {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Heading */
#header {
float:left;
margin-left: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #D9411E;
z-index: 2;
position: fixed;
font-size: 50px;
bottom: -50px;
}

/* CSS for the heading div */
#headerdiv {
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1;
position: fixed;
width: 99%;
margin-top: -20px;
height: 100px;
background-color: white;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Css for the links */
a {
    z-index: 3;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* CSS for the normal paragraphs */
.paragraph {
color: white;
font-family: Courier, serif;
}
```

P.S. I don't believe this matters, but I am on OSX using sublime text 2.

Comment: For whatever reason, you are using a negative margin, which is most likely having something to do with it. That and it's position is fixed.

Comment: I like to use negative margins sometimes, as margin-top basically means that the object is going downward, vice versa. So if I use a negative margin on say, margin-top. That means the tag will move upwards, rather than downwards. However, I will switch it and see if it changes anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt understand what are you trying to do but, `#headerdiv` overlays your link.

You can give `z-index = -1` value to your `#headerdiv` to send it back.

Comment: Both fixes work, can you explain to me how the headerdiv overlays my link, even though the z-index of the link is higher?

Comment: Because their positionings are different. If you set positioning of the element `a` as fixed, you can see that also fixes your problem but also causes you more trouble.

Comment: also, i did set the position of my link to absolute (as i want the header to stay there when i scroll down)

Answer (score 0):

little Change in css will work here

```
#headerdiv {
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1;
/*position: fixed; this is creating problem*/
width: 99%;
margin-top: -20px;
height: 100px;
background-color: white;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Both fixes work, can you please explain to me why removing position: fixed works? (cause i kinda need the div and the header to stay there so when i scroll down they stay in place)